install4j Warning: JDK with JDK 11 not available
While building my installer, it is throwing a warning as below
The JDK with name "JDK 11" has not been configured in this install4j installation (config file C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\install4j\v10\config.xml). 
As a fallback, a suitable JDK will be downloaded with the settings from the "General Settings->JRE Bundles" step.

How do I configure this to resolve this warning while build.
I am upgrading my application from Java 8 to Java 11 and for the Java 11 compatibility upgrading install4j from 7.x to 10.x.
I've changed bundled JRE to Jetbrains Runtime 11/11.0.1.
While building installer getting above Warning. Where else it should be configured to update the exact Java version in config.xml file as per warning.

a JDK is something different than a "Jetbrains Runtime"

How are you using install4j? Maybe you can make a sample project that targets java 11, something we can confirm the problem with?

@Luuk I know, that is why I am confused. Where to configure this. We have only JRE bundle option in install4j. Where we need to set this JDK to remove this warning?

see  here: In IntelliJ IDEA, you can download a JDK package right from the IDE, or you can manually download the necessary JDK distribution and define it in the IDE.

This warning is shown because you have configured a separate JDK for the code editor, like this:

This setting only affects the script editor and script compilation. These JDK configurations are saved in the global config file, the project file only references the name of the JDK configuration which is "JDK 11" in your case. On the build machine, no such configuration has been made. To fix this warning, you would have to copy the config file from your build machine to the build machine (invoke "Help->Show Directories->Show Directory Containing the Global Config File" in the main menu to find the config file).
However, when you bundle a generated JRE bundle (under General Settings->JRE bundles), you should just select "Automatic JRE download" in the dialog above and the correct JDK will be downloaded automatically.
